# poincare metric on unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega=B(a,r)$ is a ball in unit disc $D$.Prove that $\Omega$ is also a ball under the poincare metric of $D$.(poincare metric on unit disk $ds^2=\frac{2|dz|}{(1-|z|^2)}$).

I meet this problem in Ahlfors's book and I wonder whether it has a formula to calculate the center and radius.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model has formulas though they are generally complicated; one can prove this directly showing that there is a  disc automorphism (which preserves the hyperbolic metric by default) sending the above to an euclidean disc centered at zero and those are also hyperbolic discs - since disc automorphisms preserve Euclidan circles too, the only issue is to show you can get center at origin and a continuity argument will do it there without explicit computations